# Find control points to draw arc on ellipse

Tags: objective-c, draw, ellipse, geometric-arc

i want to draw an arc on ellipse. i dont know how to draw arc using curve, drawing arc with direct arc method wont help, since they are for drawing arc on circles(objective c)

on further searching i came to know elliptical arc can be drawn using control points. how i can find the control points for an arc.

i know the center point of ellipse(not two foci), start angle, end angle, the two points where the angles meet on the ellipse. from these how i can find the two control points.

or what else is missing to solve this

thanks in advance

---

its saying i can't upload images as i have low reputation.
check this : https://s3.amazonaws.com/abduBla/testfile.png

any way. the ellipse is drawn using rectangle.
what all values i should found to get the control points. what is the minimum and simplest method to find the control points

Comment: You can use the CGPath or UIBezierPath arc functions to draw an elliptical, non-circular arc.  Use `CGContextScaleCTM` with different values for the xscale and yscale parameters.

Comment: http://www.spaceroots.org/documents/ellipse/elliptical-arc.pdf